# Orion Subscription missing notification

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

Problem Description:
I have configured Orion subscription with default throttle value. The data is flowing continuously and I am able to receive the data on subscribed endpoint.
Though sometimes I am not able to get any notification though the entity gets updated.
I even checked into the tcpdump but there also i could not see notification URL being hit by the subscription.
Could you please help me with the reason for this?

subscription notifications should not be missed.

Comment: Orion version 2.2.0-next

Answer (score 0):

You must provide complete information about your scenario. Entities, subscriptions and updates.

There is not enough information to provide meaningful help or support.

Best